# Connect to X11-server from docker without xhost but with xauth

Tags: docker, docker-compose, x11, x11-forwarding

*DISCLAIMER*: This question has been asked in different forms on Stackoverflow and other venues, but I could get none to work. So I hope someone can help me figure this out once and for all.

I need to enable x11-forwarding work on my Docker container without using `xhost` at all, because of the security issues. I want to expose the `/tmp/.X11-unix` socket and `~/.Xauthority` to the Docker container, so that it can use them to connect to the X-server like a client.

I could boil down my problem to a simple `Dockerfile`. I have a `docker-compose.yml` to run that `Dockerfile`.

**`Dockerfile`**:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y x11-apps xauth
```

**`docker-compose.yml`**:

```
version: '2.3'
services:
  test:
    build: .
    command: /bin/bash
    environment:
      DISPLAY: $DISPLAY
    volumes:
      - /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix
      - ~/.Xauthority:/root/.Xauthority
```

The two files are located in the same folder. To run:

```sh
# To build the container
$ docker-compose up --build
# To run it
$ docker-compose run test

# In the container run:
$ xclock

# See the xauth list
$ xauth list
```

If you run `xhost +` in the host system, authentications will be waived from the X-server and the `xclock` program will run successfully. Otherwise, it will complain that `Error: Can't open display: :0`.
I want to solve this issue **without** `xhost`, and merely by establishing a successful connection to the X-server through the exposed socket and X authentications. Any helps on that?

**Operating System**: Ubuntu 16.04

**Docker Version**: 18.09.1, build 4c52b90

**docker-compose** version: 1.23.2, build 1110ad01

Comment: Any leads on this? I'm struggling with a similar problem as well I could not find any way to solve it yet. I also have a constraint that I cannot use network_mode: "host" because I have multiple containers talking to each other...

Answer (score 5):

Your setup was almost correct, you just need to change the `network_mode` to `host`. Otherwise, docker will create a separate network for the container, hence we are not able to connect to the host xServer instance.

Please tryout this docker-compose file:

```yaml
version: '2.3'
services:
  test:
    build: .
    command: /bin/bash
    environment:
      DISPLAY: $DISPLAY
    volumes:
      - /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix
      - ~/.Xauthority:/root/.Xauthority
    network_mode: "host"
```

In case you stick to the simple command line instead of compose:

```sh
docker run --rm -it --network host -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /home/<hostUser>/.Xauthority:/home/<containerUser>/.Xauthority -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix <container>
```

Please checkout this tutorial for more information: https://www.cloudsavvyit.com/10520/how-to-run-gui-applications-in-a-docker-container/

Comment: i assume the runtime user is root here?